# How to remove the 'is null error' in Flutter BLOC pattern?

Tags: android, flutter, error-handling, bloc

When I run my app and select a dog breed of my choice and like it, I get an error saying -

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'contains' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: contains(Instance of 'BreedsModel')
```

The likedList list contains all the dog breeds that I have liked. How do I solve this problem?

Here is the link to my code -
[My Code](https://github.com/soham1sawant/DogApp/tree/hydrated_bloc)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're calling the contains function on a null variable.

try printing the variable on which you're calling contains function.

```
print(likedList);
//output will "null"
```

make sure you're handling the null values